# How to mock creation of text files python2.7 in unitest framework?

Tags: python-2.7, mocking, patch, python-unittest

I have a function that first examines whether a txt file exists and if it does not it creates one. If the txt file already exists it reads the info. I am trying to write unittests to examine whether the logic of the function is correct. I want to patch things like existence of files, creation of files and reading of files.
The function to be tested looks like this:

```
import json
import os.path

def read_create_file():

    filename = 'directory/filename.txt'
    info_from_file = []

    if os.path.exists(filename):

        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            content = f.readlines()
            for i in range(len(content)):
                info_from_file.append(json.loads(content[i]))
        return info_from_file

    else:
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            pass

        return []
```

The unittest looks like this:

```
import unittest
import mock
from mock import patch


class TestReadCreateFile(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def function(self):
        return read_create_file()

    @patch("os.path.exists", return_value=False)
    @mock.patch('directory/filename.txt.open', new=mock.mock_open())
    def test_file_does_not_exist(self, mock_existence, mock_open_patch):
        result = self.function()
        self.assertEqual(result, (True, []))
```

ERROR: ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.

or like this:

```
import unittest
import mock
from mock import patch

@patch("os.path.exists", return_value=False)
def test_file_not_exist_yet(self, mock_existence):
    m = mock.mock_open()
    with patch('__main__.open', m, create=True):
        handle = open('directory/filename.txt', 'w')
    result = self.function()

    self.assertEqual(result, (True, {}))
```

ERROR:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'directory/filename.txt'

As a newbie I cannot seem to get my head around a solution, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're mocking os.path.exists wrong. When you patch you patch from the file under test.

```
@patch("path_to_method_under_test.path.exists", return_value=False)
def test_file_not_exist_yet(self, mock_existence):
```